# Split large binary file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a quite big binary file that contains the information in a volume of about one GB of data.

I am trying to split one GB of `.bin` file into 4 files of 256 MB each, I am getting no help.

I tried using `textscan` and `memmapfile` functions but of no use.

Any help on this?

Comment: give more explain  with your code .

Comment: `textscan` isn't for binary files. Try `fread`.

Comment: Please explain what you tried to do, and how it didn't work. "I am getting no help" is completely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB can both read and write binary files.

Try using the `fopen()`, `fread()`/`fwrite()`, and `fclose()` commands.

To read a binary file into MATLAB, first *open* the file for reading.

Then the magic comes -- you need to know the context/structure of the binary data inside the `.bin` file so as to be able to scan the data thereafter into variables **using the correct format**.

```
fHANDLE         = fopen( 'aHugeBinFileNAME.bin','r'); % Open the binary file for reading with a fileHandle fHANDLE
[dVECTOR,count] = fread( fHANDLE, 'int16' );          % Scan the data into a vector of int16 values, in this case called dVECTOR
fclose( fHANDLE);                                     % Close the file
```

Anyway, get more details about fileIO services via `help fread()` et al on more options to read "first/next" 256MB of the huge input-file for your specific context of use.

```
dVECTOR_256M = fread( fHANDLE, 256*1024*1024, 'uint8', 0, 'b' ); % Big-Endian convention
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am seeing the following error may be due to my RAM size, "Error using fread
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options."

Comment: Sure, low level access to .bin files allows you to work in a sliding-window manner ( both on `fread()`-s from an input-stream-of-bytes & `fwrite()`-s to the output-stream-of-bytes ) so that your memory resources do not get devastated by a lack of any ( rather explicit ) control over their ( intrinsically inefficient ) blind & unreasonably optimistic mode of use. One more thing to take into consideration besides RAM-memory. Due to aDiskIO alignment of HDD-units-of-storage, an actual size to `fread()`/`fwrite()` shall not go less than about 16 * 64kB file-chunks ( goes far beyond the OP topic ).

Comment: Is there any way that i can get rid of this memory issue?

Comment: Sure, do not `fread()` more than a few MBs ( ref. previous comment ) and `fwrite()` 'em to the output-file. Also might get pipe-lined without a trouble with a double buffer-allocations as in a sliding-window processing similar to this:  `fwrite( anOutputFileHANDLE, fread( anInputFileHANDLE, aReasonableMemoryChunkSIZE, 'uint8', aFileSegmentBaseOffsetBYTES + aLoopIncrementCOUNTER * aReasonableMemoryChunkSIZE, 'b' ) ); %% enclosed in a for-loop to slide over the whole input file`.